# Gmaps showing grey area until screen is resized

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When the modal loads the map portion is showed grey but on resizing window it appears but again disappears on reloading the page.

[here is how the map is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0n2s.png)

```
f($("#google_ptm_map").length > 0){
        var gPTMCords = new google.maps.LatLng(29.867865, 77.891575);
        var gPTMOptions = {zoom: 16,center: gPTMCords, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}    
        var gPTM = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_ptm_map"), gPTMOptions);        

        var cords = new google.maps.LatLng(29.864865, 77.896575);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: cords, map: gPTM, title: "Marker 1"});
```

}

```
            <div id="google_ptm_map" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: this can happen when you don't have the map div visible at the startup  ..

Comment: I am using it map inside a modal and it is visible only when link is clicked

Comment: then you must invoke the function for show the map  when you activated the modal .. otherwise you have ever a grey map at modal opening